# C++ - How to place element after front of std::list?

Tags: c++

So, I'm trying to insert an element after the front of a std::list but there doesn't seem to be any standard library methods that support it.

My attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> listy;
    listy.push_back(1);
    listy.push_back(3);
    // listy.emplace(listy.begin() + 1,2); won't work!
    
    for (int a : listy)
        std::cout << a << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware `rbegin()` would work in this case, but I want a method relative to the start of the list.

Comment: You can find the list of member functions for all standard types at cppreference. See [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: You question boils down to "how do I replace listy.begin() + 1?"